# get value from json with dynamic key

Tags: json

My JScript is:

```
var t={'color':'red'}; // dynamic json data.
for(n in t)
{
    alert(n)
}
```

here, alert gives the json key **color**. but how to get its value?

Note: the json is dynamic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var t={'color':'red'}; // dynamic json data.
for(n in t)
{
    alert(n);// n = key
    var val =t[n];// value where key is n

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example to get dynamic keys from json response - [Get dynamic keys from JSON Data](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/get-dynamic-keys-from-json-data/)

```
public void getData(String data){
    // Load json data and display
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
// Use loop to get keys from your response
Iterator itr = jsonData.keys();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    String keys = (String)itr.next();
Log.e("Keys", "----"+keys);

JSONArray dynamicValue = jsonData.getJSONArray(keys);

    // Your stuff here
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t={'color':'red'}; // dynamic json data.
for(n in t)
{
    alert(t[n])
}
```

Answer (score -2):

instead of putting the n in al alert put it in an external variable or something...

Edited, try sometnihg like this:

```
var ex_n;
var t={'color':'red'};

for(var i=0; i<t.length; i++) ex_n = t[i]["color"];
```

Comment: it gives the same output 'color'. but I want to access its value dynamically

Comment: This would work for standard arrays without keys, his problem with associative arrays. see vikrant singh's answer

Comment: Yes but this also works with an associative array(if you know the name of the key), try yourself..