# Get JSON specific value using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a json which is generated through php and i assigned it to a JS variable like below,

```
var jsonObj =  {
    "ATF":["FLV"],
    "Limecase":["FLV"],
    "RCF":["FLV","HTTP","PALM","MOBILE","3GP","H263","F263","WMV"],
    "Wave":["FLV","IPHONE","MOBILE"]
}
```

And also i have a selectbox in html as below,

```
<select id="selectbox" data-rel="chosen"> 
    <option value='ATF'>ATF</option>
    <option value='Limespace'>Limespace</option>
    <option value='RCF'>RCF</option>
    <option value='Wave'>Wave</option>
</select>
```

On changing, i am getting the selected value and passing it as below,

`alert(jsonObj.selVal);` but alert throws "undefined"

But if i give direct value `jsonObj.ATF`, it gives FLV.

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get value from json with dynamic key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591380/get-value-from-json-with-dynamic-key)

Comment: this question has been asked multiple times already....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selVal = 'ATF'; // or from an input
alert(jsonObj[selVal]);
```

Comment: why it is throwing undefined?, if i try like jsonObj.selVal.

Comment: @Yadheendran Because it looks for a property "selVal". This does not exist.